# Using Slick Carousel with Views - How to setup a slideshow with View

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to setup a [slick carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick) slideshow. I've created a content type for the images and added a few nodes to the content type with images. I then created a View block...but see no option to format with 'slick carousel'. [This article](https://www.studio-umi.jp/blog/responsive-slideshow-slick) says to choose 'slick carousel' instead of format: unformatted list (but I don't see this option).

The only place I see the ability to choose 'slick carousel' is in the content: image field itself under 'Fields'. But when I choose it there - not surprisingly - it shows no results. If I leave it as the default it shows the images. But, of course, I want not just a block of the images from the nodes but a SLIDESHOW.

Does anyone know how to make this work with Slick Carousel? Thanks.

*Note: I have installed the required libraries and the .min.js file*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Slick views](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_views) module.

> Slick views adds a new display style to views called **Slick
>   carousel**. Similar to how you select **HTML** List or **Unformatted**
>   List as display styles.

Comment: Ha, well that was an easy fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: Make sure you have the slick views module installed and enabled along with the slick module.
Check this site as it might help: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-slick-slideshow/